# Magento - custom filters on product list page

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I ma trying to create 2 filters for a product list page, one for `price` and the other for a custom attribute I have made; `location`

Ideally, what I'd like is a drop down, with the price ranges and another dropdown with the locations and a submit button, which will then filter.

I've had a look round, but I can't seem to find any examples of how to implements this.

On a default Magento store i have locally, I have the layered navigation (on the left) and filtering gives me a URL of: `index.php/products?location=7&dir=asc&order=position&price=3%2C1000`

So the dropdown filters will need to emulate this, if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do this manually with html and pass in the parameters to the search query string.